# iOS8 calendar events in Notifications

Tags: iphone, calendar, notifications, ios

I use Calendar on my iPhone, for school timetable. So the lessons are displayed in the Notifications. But I have discovered, that after updating my phone to iOS8, there is a weird bug. On tuesdays, I see the monday lessons, (after reseting the phone, it gets back to normal - shows the correct day). Every other day this works without a problem...

Does anyone else have the same problem and any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: what is your setting for "work" days/hours in calender?

Comment: Where do I find this settings?